# Force MAven build of Child pom on JENKINS to pull latest version of parent pom before execution

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have maven inheritance setup for my project build. Project A is defined as parent on Project B and Project C.
Inheritance on Project B pom.xml is as below

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>Project A</artifactId>
        <groupId>path to Project A</groupId>
        <version>2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
<build>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>path to Project C</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project C</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Version of Project C; used as dependency on Project B is defined in Project A which is parent to both B and C and many of other builds.

Problem is when Project C and Project B are updated :-

1. I build Project C first, which is a success.
2. I build Project A, with updated version of project C, which also is success on node **<Node 01>** of Jenkins. Note, I cannot update the version of Project A ( this because there are other child pom those are also using verison 2).
3. But on executing Project B, which gets executed on **<Node 02>** of JENKINS, it fails because it could not find updated version of Project C via Project A. If we point and run Project B on **<Node 01>** where Project A was built, Project B succeeds as well.

So the question is, is there a way to force the build for Project B to always pull the defined version of parent pom ;Project A, even if that version is already present on the Jenkins **<Node 02>** (from earlier or other build) and then run the project B specific build.

Thanks in advance